# How to create an unnumbered subsection in a subsection?

Tags: sectioning

> **2 Measurement Setup**
>
> Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some >text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text >some text some text
>
> **2.1 Radar Equipment**
>
> Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some >text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text >some text some text
>
> **2.1.1 Ultra Wideband Radar**
>
> Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some >text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text >some text some text
>
> **M-Sequence Pseudo-Noise Generator**
>
> Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some >text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text >some text some text
>
> **Dual-Polarized Vivaldi Antenna**
>
> Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some >text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text >some text some text
>
> **2.1.2 Frequency Modulated Continuous Wave Radar**
>
> Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some >text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text >some text some text
>
> **2.2 Stepper Motors**
>
> **2.3 Test Objects**

I am not clear on how to create the bold text unnumbered sections and I don't want to have more then 3 Levels

Comment: `\subsection*{Wombat}`

Comment: @Johannes_B this works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unnumbered sections you can use `\subsection*{subsection name}`. The levels of table of content you can define with `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`  or numbering with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}`.

Unnumbered section:

```
\chapter{First One}
\section{A section}
\section{B section}

\section*{unnumbered section}
```

[image]

**Update:You can add them to table of content manualy with `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section name}`.**

Only  3 Levels in toc with `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`.

```
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{B section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsection}
```

[image]

Full Code example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}   
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First One}
\section{A section}
\section{B section}

\section*{unnumbered section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{unnumbered section}
I am not clear on how to create the bold text unnumbered sections
\section{fcf}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{B section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsection}


\end{document}
```